# R-2R ladder current DAC general formula

Tags: dac

I am looking for a formula for R-2R current mode and voltage mode
is there some source where there is general formulas for these two?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You'll learn a lot if you work it out for yourself.

Comment: how can i see from these circuits that its voltage mode or current mode?
Thanks.

Comment: I've never worked this out but I can see a difference. Notice that in voltage mode the resistor chain runs from Vout to ground whereas in the current mode it runs from Vref to ground. By the way, you need to give credit to the author of those images. It's site policy.